# "Error: Missing script 'dev' when running 'npm run dev'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite

I am encountering an error message when attempting to run the command npm run dev in my project. The error states: "npm ERR! Missing script: 'dev'". It suggests running npm run to see a list of available scripts.

I have checked my package.json file and ensured that the "scripts" section contains a script named "dev". However, the error persists. I have also verified that I am running the correct command and that all necessary dependencies are installed using npm i.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit":"^1.9.1",
    "axios":"^1.2.2",
    "dayjs":"^1.11.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar":"^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component":"^6.1.0",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component":"^1.5.6",
    "react-player":"^2.11.0",
    "react-redux":"^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom":"^6.6.2",
    "react-select":"^5.7.0",
    "sass":"^1.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

error :-

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lodhi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-18T22_58_14_424Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with vite and autocompletion of tailwind classes. I was able to solve it by removing the following line from package.json.

```
type: "module"
```

Please give it a shot.